# cfn-hup "on.demand" trigger in Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cloudformation

I've used cfn-hup for various projects, and have followed the [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-hup.html) for cfn-hup. As documented on that page, there are the following trigger types listed:

- post.add
- post.update
- post.remove

I've used these to great success. Recently, I was reviewing an Elastic Beanstalk CloudFormation template for learning purposes. Elastic Beanstalk uses CloudFormation to provision and bootstrap resources. They use cfn-hup, but have a weird trigger type in their configuration file:

```
"\/etc\/cfn\/hooks.d\/aws-eb-command-handler.conf":{
  "content":{
    "Fn::Join":[
      "",
      [
        "[aws-eb-command-handler]",
        "\n",
        "triggers=on.command",
        "\n",
        "path=ElasticBeanstalkCommand-",
        "AWSEBAutoScalingGroup",
        "\n",
        "action=commandWrapper.py",
        "\n"
      ]
    ]
  }
},
```

As you can see, they have an "on.command" trigger type. Maybe I'm blind, but I can't find that documented anywhere. Is this some special internal trigger type that only Elastic Beanstalk is allowed to use? Or is this just yet another undocumented feature, and if so what does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This hook type is indeed an under-documented one.

**on.command** is CloudFormation's way to tie your cfn-hup commands to an SQS-queue.

To use it configure your SQS queue in the main section:

```
[main]
sqs_url=https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/XXXXXXXX/cfn-hook-trigger
```

Then upon a message to that queue, your command will be executed on the instance. The message format is as follows:

```
{
"InvocationId": "unique",
 "DispatcherId": "some value, participating in message and leader elections",
 "Expiration": "1433617216000", //timestamp
 "CommandName": "cfn-auto-reloader-hook", //or any other hook name
 "ResultQueue": "https://eu-west-1.queue.amazonaws.com/...", // mandatory if hook.send_result was
initialized
 "Data": null, //will populate ENV[CMD_DATA] env var; optional
 "EventHandle": null //will populate ENV[EVENT_HANDLE] env var; optional
}
```

If send_result=True for the chosen hook, then a specified ResultQueue is used to dump the execution result in. The message format is as follows:

```
{
"DispatcherId" : "copied from the inbound message",
 "InvocationId" : "copied from the inbound message",
 "CommandName" : "copied from the inbound message",
 "Status" : "FAILURE" | "SUCCESS",
 "ListenerId" : "FQDN or AWS instance id if applicable",
 "Data": "STDOUT", // data > 1Kb is treated as FAILURE
 "Message": "STDERR, if $? != 0" //or first 100 bytes of STDOUT if it was > 1Kb
}
```

The information here was mined from the [python sources](https://s3.amazonaws.com/cloudformation-examples/aws-cfn-bootstrap-latest.tar.gz) as of June 2015.

It was not actually tested.

Also, AWS may have changed the behaviour, since it's not even documented.